# How can Type int[] implement interfaces that do not yet exist (for me)?

Tags: c#, .net

Today I tested the following code in Visual Studio 2010 (.NET Framework version 4.0)

```
Type[] interfaces = typeof(int[]).GetInterfaces();
```

And I was shocked to find these two on the list:

> System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>
> System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[[System.Int32,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

I have used these two interfaces before in environments with framework 4.5+ installed, and according to the documentation, [both](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542(v=vs.110).aspx) [of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx) them were created for 4.5. This does **not** compile in my environment:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<int> list = new int[3];
```

> The type or namespace name 'IReadOnlyCollection' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Collections.Generic' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

When I try this:

```
int[] array = new int[3];
Type iReadOnlyCollection = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
int count = (int)iReadOnlyCollection.GetProperty("Count").GetValue(array, null);
```

`count` equals 3, as expected. What is going on here?

**Edit:** I do not think framework 4.5 is installed on my machine:

**Edit 2:** Thanks @ScottChamberlain, it turns out I did have it installed.

Comment: `new System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<int>();` is attempting to new up an interface; this will never compile, regardless of .NET version.

Comment: @MetroSmurf thanks...durp

Comment: About your edit: see [To find .NET Framework versions by viewing the registry (.NET Framework 4.5 and later)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#net_b) for how to check for versions later than 4.0.

Comment: Also see [Identifying the .NET version you are running (2.0, 4.5, 4.5.1 or 4.5.2)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2014/12/23/identifying-the-net-version-you-are-running-2-0-4-5-4-5-1-or-4-5-2/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[.NET 4.5 is an in-place update for .NET 4](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx). This means that while in visual studio you cannot reference `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` while targeting .NET 4, the runtime has this type available if you have the 4.5 update installed.

Try running your code in an environment where you don't have the .NET 4.5 update (i.e., just 4.0) and the code will not find the interface type. I.e., `` Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1... `` would return `null`, and `typeof(int[]).GetInterfaces()` will not contain the interfaces you mentioned.

Comment: I don't believe I have 4.5 installed on my machine - see addition to question

Comment: @MrAnderson 4.5 still shows up as 4.0 in the registery, [you need to look at the build number](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2014/12/23/identifying-the-net-version-you-are-running-2-0-4-5-4-5-1-or-4-5-2/)

Answer (score 4):

You're compiling for .NET 4.0, so 4.5-specific types aren't seen by the compiler.

You're running on .NET 4.5 or 4.6, so 4.5-specific types are seen by the runtime.

If you were expecting your application to run on .NET 4.0: you can't. .NET 4.5 and 4.6 are in-place upgrades. Once installed, your system no longer has .NET 4.0 on it. You can still run .NET 4.0 applications, as .NET 4.5 and 4.6 are largely backwards compatible, and that runtime environment will simply be used instead.

Comment: I don't believe I have 4.5 installed on my machine - see addition to question